# What does the element of homology groups mean?

Tags: homology-cohomology

I am studying homology groups for topological spaces.
I do not understand how the element of homology groups play roles.

For example,let $T^2$ be a 2-dim torus.
I think meridian $m$ and longitude $l$ of $T^2$ play a generator of 1-dim homology group of $T^2$ $H_1(T^2)$, so we denote the generator of $H_1(T^2)$ by $[m]$ and $[l]$ respectively.But, what is the $[m]+[l]$ in $H_1(T^2)$?
How curve is it in $T^2$, and why?
And what is $2[m]$ in $H_1(T^2)$?

In general, what is the generator of homology groups?
And what do the sum of the elements of homology groups mean?

Comment: I think the introduction of chapter $2$ of Hatcher about homology was useful for me when I started algebraic topology. Just a small remark : you say "what is this curve" : here there is a curve in $T^2$ which has class $[m] + [l]$ : the curve $(t,t)$ in the torus = square with boundary indentification. In general you can imagine a cycle as "virtual union" of differents subvarieties (image of simplexes in your space) which is "closed". In particular $2[m]=[m] + [m]$ also make sense. I suggest to do some exercises with homology for being for familiar : this is a really nice and geometric theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take the easiest question first: The sum is a so-called *formal sum*. That means basically that the addition means as little as it can. For instance, $[l]+[m]$ means "We have one copy of the class $[m]$, and one copy of the class $[l]$." The sum $3[m] - 2[l]$ means "We have two copies of the class $[m]$ and negative three copies of the class $[l]$."

As for the generators, here I have to go a bit in-depth about what homology groups *are*. They are a quotient group of a certain subgroup of the group $C_n$ of $n$-chains. Exactly what these $n$-chains are depends on which interpretation of homology you're using, but in singular homology, they're (formal) sums of functions $f:\Delta^n\to X$, where $X$ is your space, $\Delta^n$ is the standard $n$-dimensional [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).

We also have a so-called *boundary map* $d$ that takes an $n$-chain to an $n-1$-chain by restricting any $f$ to all the (oriented hyper-)faces of $\Delta^n$ in turn (with alternating signs). For instance, if $f:\Delta^2\to X$ is a triangle, then $d(f)$ is the "alternating sum of its edges, with orientation". The important thing about which signs and which orientations you use is this: Given *any* $n$-chain $c = a_1f_1 + \cdots + a_kf_k$, we must have $d(d(c)) = 0$ as an $(n-2)$-chain.

The subgroup of $C_n$ given by all $n$-chains $c$ for which $d(c) = 0$ is called the group of *cycles*, $Z_n$. A typical example of an element in $Z_1$ is a loop, in $Z_2$ it's a sphere, and so on. The subgroup of $C_n$ consisting of all chains $c$ for which there is an $(n+1)$-chain $c'$ with $d(c') = c$ is called the group of *boundaries*. A typical example is the boundary of a disc for $n = 1$, or the boundary of a ball, for $n = 2$. The above "$d(d(c)) = 0$ for all $c$" means that we have $B_n \subseteq Z_n$. The $n$-th homology group, $H_n$, is defined as the quotient $Z_n/B_n$. It represents the cycles which cannot be "filled in" within your space.

The generators of the homology group are usually taken to be an equivalence classes represented by a specific cycle-which-is-not-a-boundary. In your example, we choose the representatives $m$ and $l$, since these are two loops that are not the boundary of a disc. Of course, as with any group, you can't choose any set as generators. You need to choose elements that actually *generate* the group. But that's more of a question in general group theory, not homology.